# What is the adjective for PHAGE?

Tags: microbiology, philosophy-of-science

if the adjective of the noun BACTERIUM is 'bacterial' and that of VIRUS is 'viral', what is the adjective for (BACTERIO)PHAGE? Is '**phagial**' accepted?

Thank you

Comment: Bacteriophages are viruses so what's wrong with viral?

Comment: @Cell "Bacteriophages"!? Not to be a grammar-nazi, but bacteriophage is an unchanging irregular noun. The plural of bacteriophage is bacteriophage. The plural of phage is phage.

Comment: @MikeyC If it's good enough to be acceptable on Nature's educational website, it's good enough for me: https://www.nature.com/scitable/definition/bacteriophage-phage-293/#:~:text=A%20bacteriophage%20is%20a%20type,surrounded%20by%20a%20protein%20structure Not to mention it is also found in published work: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3109452/

Comment: Have you done a Google search for "phagial"? You might [try and see what you find](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). (And there is no need to use capitals. On the internet that is considered to be shouting.)

Comment: can you give a context in which you want to use it?

Comment: The context would be: "there were 32 phagous species in our samples". (as opposed to 50 bacterial and 12 viral species).

Comment: @Cell. I learned something today. Thanks for supporting your usage. It seems both are acceptable. The invariant form was just drilled into me for 5 years of undergrad and 6 years of grad school. Seriously, my PhD advisor would interrupt a research talk to correct something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **bacteriophagous** as given in wiktionary.

> From bacterio- (“bacteria”) +‎ -phagous (“eating”).

[Reference](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/bacteriophagous)

Comment: This is what I found by googling it and hence shared with the reference. Why downvote then?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this would seem to me to be an adjective modifying "virus" (e.g. a phage is a "bacteriophagous virus") rather than an adjective modifying something associated with a phage "phagial(?) population growth", "phagial(?) biochemistry", etc.)

Comment: I downvoted this answer for 2 reasons: (1) a search for "bacteriophagous" on PubMed yields very few results (only 25), and (2) from the context of those results, "bacteriophagous" means a "bacteria-eating" or "bacteria-engulfing"; not bacteriophage-like.

Answer (score 1):

In the literature, it's most common to see hyphenated compound adjectives, like "phage-mediated," "phage-dependent," or "phage-encoded" where "bacterial" or "viral" might be analogous. For example, ["Phage‐mediated selection and the evolution and maintenance of restriction‐modification."](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/28568719/)

Sometimes "phage" seems to be used as a standalone adjective, like in ["Phage antibodies: filamentous phage displaying antibody variable domains."](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/2247164/) Although I'm not sure that it would be correct to use "bacterial antibodies" or "viral antibodies" in this case, so maybe that one is an anomaly.

I would suggest following one of these trends, unless you want to do a lot of explaining to reviewers.

Comment: so something like "pagial/phagous species" should become phage-species, right?

Comment: In that case, you would probably not use the hyphen. There's some discussion of naming conventions in this article on PubMed, and they do use the phrase "phage species." https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5408676/.

Comment: I read the article, but the space is related to naming the phage itself, not the adjective for phage...

Comment: I only referenced it to give you an example of how "phage species" might be used appropriately. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I asked the author of that paper and she replied: "I have never in my career heard anyone use the terms phagial or phagous." Probably "phage-species" of "phage species" is the more accepted way, 'phage' being (I presume) a modifier more than a real adjective.

Comment: From the University of Wyoming (courtesy Prof. Suess) I got: "I would go with phagial.   Following the Latin ending for viral, bacterial: `-ial - (Latin: a suffix that forms English adjectives from Latin adjectives ending with -is or -ius with meanings about "pertaining to, relating to", or "characterized by")`"